# Reasons why Places APIs are auto-disabled in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, configuration, google-places-api

I enabled the Places API on Google Cloud Platform a week ago and I was able to use the Places API just fine.

However, just today, I found that I started getting Error 403 on my request ("Places API (New) has not been used in project XXXXXXXXXX before or it is disabled"). When signing in to the Google Cloud console, I noticed that I needed to enable it again.

Is there a reason why the Places API service got disabled automatically on Google Cloud Platform?

These are some things I have done to troubleshoot the issue:

1. I have 'enabled service' to check that it was disabled (it was disabled)
2. I have confirmed that GCP logs these actions correctly (as shown in the screenshot below)
   [image]
3. If I assume (2) is correct, then there should be a 'disable service' log somewhere between 7 days ago and today, but it was not there in the screenshot
4. I have checked the activity logs and there were no 'disable service' record between these two timeframes
   [image]
5. Checked with other team members whether they disabled the service accidentally. But no one did so.

Comment: Hello! I'd suggest that you file a support case so that tech support agents can check your project and other stuff. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support